# Como publicar base de dados .mdf no Azure SQL Dabases?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sql-server, code-first, microsoft-azure, migrations

Tenho uma `solution` com um projeto `Asp.Net MVC 5` e estou utilizando `Code First` e `Migrations` para atualizar a base de dados `.mdf` gerada automaticamente na pasta App_Data. Como faço para colocar esse `.mdf` no `Azure` e poder usar o mesmo em produção?

Answer (score 2):

Você terá que gerar um script desse arquivo `MDF` e conectar na base Azure utilizando o SQL Server Management Studio. O procedimento é meio grande e não caberia na resposta (teria que ser uma resposta em separado só pra isso). Como curiosidade, neste link tem o passo a passo de como anexar seu `MDF` numa instância de SQL Server (http://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/02/13/how-can-i-open-mdf-and-ldf-files-in-sql-server-attach-tutorial-troublshooting/).

Lembrando que no Azure não é possível anexar um .mdf. A forma mais simples é ter o SQL SErver Management Studio e usar a opção de *deploy* da sua base para o SQL Azure.

Alternativamente, você pode configurar o método `Seed` do seu arquivo `Migrations\Configuration.cs` para que os dados sejam inseridos na publicação do seu sistema na nuvem Azure:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Models.ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        ContextKey = "SeuSistema.Models.ApplicationDbContext";
    }

    protected override void Seed(SeuSistema.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```